# Regular expression to break string into float/alpha parts

Tags: c#, regex

I am trying to match `double[M|B]` into double part and alpha part. For example, `47.5B`, or `350M`.

This doesn't work:

```
var numAlpha = new Regex("(<Numeric>^[0-9]*?:\\.[0-9]*)(<Alpha>[a-zA-Z]+)");
var match = numAlpha.Match("1.65B");

var number = match.Groups["Numeric"].Value;
var alpha = match.Groups["Alpha"].Value;
```

Comment: First: The syntax of named groups is wrong. Second: your numeric-regex will ---- its ---: Try: [`(?<Numeric>\d+(?:\.\d+)?)(?<Alpha>[a-zA-Z]+)`](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3f%3cNumeric%3e%5cd%2b%28%3f%3a%5c.%5cd%2b%29%3f%29%28%3f%3cAlpha%3e%5ba-zA-Z%5d%2b%29&i=1.65B%0d%0a350M)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex contains several issues:

- [**Named capturing groups**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bs2twtah(v=vs.110).aspxcaret/1495/start-of-line) are formed with `(?<Name>pattern)` syntax
- A "wild" `:` symbol is present
- Your number regex matches a single `.`, too.

I suggest fixing it the following way (see [online demo](http://ideone.com/y6vI4j)):

```
var numAlpha = new Regex(@"(?<Numeric>[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+)(?<Alpha>[a-z]+)", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
var match = numAlpha.Match("1.65B");
if (match.Success) 
{
    var number = match.Groups["Numeric"].Value;
    var alpha = match.Groups["Alpha"].Value;
    Console.WriteLine("Number: {0}, Alpha: {1}", number, alpha); // DEMO!
    // => Number: 1.65, Alpha: B
}
```

Note:

- If you need to match *the whole string*, add `^` anchor at the start and `$` at the end - `@"^(?<Numeric>[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+)(?<Alpha>[a-z]+)$"`
- `RegexOptions.IgnoreCase` allows using `[a-z]` instead of `[a-zA-Z]`.

Comment: This regex matches `.3M`. Should it? Maybe `\d+(\.\d+)?` as double-pattern does a better job.

Comment: `.3` is a valid double, isn't it? See [Matching Floating Point Numbers with a Regular Expression](http://www.regular-expressions.info/floatingpoint.html). The expression is a shortened (no exponent part here) variant from there.

Comment: Maybe it's valid - I'm not sure about it. That's why I'm asking for it. But OP can decide what pattern to use. Good explanation of the mistakes he did.

Answer (score 1):

Try splitting using lookarounds which can see the difference between numeric and non numeric characters:

```
var items = Regex.Split("47.5B", "(?<=[^0-9.])(?=[0-9])|(?<=[0-9])(?=[^0-9.])");
Console.WriteLine(items[0]);
Console.WriteLine(items[1]);
```

**Output:**

```
47.5
B
```

**Demo here:**

## Rextester